# tesseract - Trained Data for Codes

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I am implementing an iOS application which uses tesseract. Right now, I am searching for an already trained data set which recognizes codes like the following:
VTE-61243, 299246, 4906-292342, W832284

Any suggestions which trained data set would be good for that purpose?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The font is very important for good results, you need to train yourself.And then you can use whitelist to recognize only A-Z letters, "-" and "," symbols ,and numbers.